# Mean First Passage Time (MFPT) of CTMC

Tags: markov-process, continuous-data

Could anyone possibly advise me on how one would go about calculating the MFPT matrix of a continuous-time Markov chain?

I've tried looking around online, but I can only find information on discrete-time Markov chains. Presumably it's more complicated than taking the exponential of the MFPT matrix of the transition matrix.

Comment: Can you spell out MFPT?

Comment: It is usual custom on CrossValidated to spell out at least once acronyms one use.  People want to understand your post without looking up other sites.  In 16 days you got 16 views and zero answers. If you need or want an answer you should cooperate!

Comment: Did you even read the title of the question?

I appreciate that you're trying to help, and I apologise for the sass - I honestly thought you were just trolling at first.